# Why I am not able to get the vox populi badge in stack overflow saying Daily post vote limit reached; vote again in 20 hours

Tags: stack, overflow, badge

Daily post vote limit reached; vote again in 20 hours.

I am not able to get the vox populi badge. I can vote only 36 votes in a day and then a message pops up saying "Daily post vote limit reached; vote again in 20 hours."
How to solve this issue.